# stuck at Guideline 5.1.1 - Legal - Privacy - Data Collection and Storage

Tags: ios, app-store

I got the following message from the App Store reviewers:

> We noticed that your app requires user to register with personal information that is not directly relevant to your app's core functionality. Specifically the following fields are required but do not appear to be directly relevant to your app's core functionality:
>
> - Date of Birth
> - Phone Number
> - Address
> - Title
>
> **Next Steps**
>
> To resolve this issue, please either remove all required fields that are not relevant to the app or make those fields optional. Information requested during registration must be relevant to the features the app provides.

([screenshot of App Store Team response quoted above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EldW.png))

I don't know what I should do. What key in the info.plist file should I use to cover this policy?

I need those data for:

- Date of Birth: product design target purpose
- phone Address: to contact the customer who have issue on their transaction
- address: to send the product to customer
- title: to email the customer as header

I've tried emailing them for above purpose, but it seems it's the chatbot that's replying.

Comment: You should make all of those fields optional as Apple has indicated. You would like to know their date of birth but that certainly isn't essential to the operation of your app. If you are going to ship physical goods then you should collect address the first time the user places an order, not when they register.  Phone and title probably should always be optional, but it may be acceptable to collect it when the user places an order

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Apple review policies